# How to move hidden config files to sub folder in the home directory

Tags: home, dot-files

I know we can config file explorer to hide hidden files, but in the open dialogue box of some program, it is not an option. I am just tired of scrolling through hidden folder and files in my home directory. Is there a way to move them into a sub folder and keep the applications working?

Comment: Do you have a certain program in mind where the open dialogue does not allow to filter out hidden files?

Comment: You could file bug reports with the programs that do not follow the [XDG standard](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html) ...

Comment: @Dubu There are many programs, some of them don't use the standard GUI kit, so it can't be controlled in the desktop settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be going against alot of UNIX momentum and history renaming your the hidden folders in you home directory, I wouldn't do it.
Not only do the existing programs expect those folders to exist but any applications you install in the future will just place more hidden folders in your home directory.
I agree its annoying - I have almost 100 files and folders in my home dir -  instead I recommend you learn how to use tools to manage listing and searching files, e.g.

Here is a  couple of ways to list ignoring hidden files:

- `ls`
- `find . -not -path '*/\.*'` 
  ==**Explanation**==> The `-path` option checks the pattern against the entire path string. `*` is a wildcard, `/` is a directory separator, `\.` is a dot (it has to be escaped to avoid special meaning), and `*` is another wildcard. `-not` means don't select files that match this test.

My personal preference is to use tmux's copy mode (with vi key bindings).

Comment: `ls` ignores hidden files by default. You have to explicitly add `-a` or `-A` to show them.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever move or delete the dot files in your home directory. This will break your environment because as stated, they hold your configuration. Some are recreated when missing and others not.